# Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute

Tags: c#, asp.net

I keep getting the following warning (not error) in a production ASP.Net application:

```
System.Web.HttpUnhandledException: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
at System.Web.UI.ControlCollection.ControlCollectionEnumerator.MoveNext()
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)
at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.Render(HtmlTextWriter output)
at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
at DMAC.UI.Master.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
at System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
at Telerik.Web.UI.RadAjaxControl.RenderPageInAjaxMode(HtmlTextWriter writer, Control page)
at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
at System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
at ASP.scan_history_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Here is the code for the Render method where the error is occurring:

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        Header header = new Header();
        List<Menu> menus = DMAC.Application.Current().Menus;
        Menu menu = menus.Find(m => m.MenuId == MenuId);

        SiteMapWindow siteWindow = new SiteMapWindow();
        siteWindow.OpenerId = Menu.PATHID;
        this.Page.Form.Controls.Add(siteWindow);

        SupportWindow supportWindow = new SupportWindow();
        supportWindow.OpenerId = Menu.SUPPORTID;
        this.Page.Form.Controls.Add(supportWindow);

        this.Page.Form.Controls.AddAt(0, menu);
        this.Page.Form.Controls.AddAt(0, header);

        Scripts.GoogleAnalytics.RegisterScript(this.Page);
        base.Render(writer);
    }
```

I cannot recreate the error myself.  Any ideas?

Comment: I don't always test my code; but when I do, I do it in production.

Comment: @Brandon, stay thirsty my friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suspect the problem arises from adding (non-child) controls in `Render`

That is, *the controls are added to the Page Control Collection which is likely being iterated over in order to Render children.* (And I am presuming that includes this code; in a child control.)

*Move* the layout modifications (really, everything in the method) into `CreateChildControls` or what may be appropriate. (I'm not sure `CreateChildControls` is actually okay here -- the issue, I believe, is the Page Controls *aren't* children.)

Happy coding.